# how to insert json data dynamically into html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```js
{
      "top10": [
            {
                  "state": "red",
                  "claimed": true,
                  "branch": "release-2.3.4",
                  "job": "sdk",
                  "culprit": "Hansi Meier"
            },
            {
                  "state": "blue",
                  "claimed": true,
                  "branch": "master",
                  "job": "ibeo-cloud",
                  "culprit": "Karl Gustavo"
            },
            {
                  "state": "yellow",
                  "claimed": false,
                  "branch": "feature-abc",
                  "job": "appbase",
                  "culprit": "MAfred Auch"
            }
      ]
 }
```

```html
<nav class="side-navbar">
        <div class="title">
          <h1>Top 10</h1>
        </div>

        <ul class="list-group">
          <a class="item d-flex align-items-center">
             
                <i class="fa fa-caret-up" style="font-size:48px;color:red"></i>
                <div class="item d-table-cell">
                 <i id='topbranch'></i>
                 <i id='topjob'></i>
                 <i id='topculprit'></i>
                </div>
                 <i class="fa fa-refresh" style="font-size:30px;color:yellow"></i>
                
            </a>
        
        </ul>
</nav>
```

[image]

I want to insert my json data into html elemnts
for example top10[0].branch should go into html id topbranch.
and it should loop. please see the image how it should come.
please show me how to do it in javascript.it would be nice if you give jsfiddle link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change all `id` to `class` for `topbranch, topjob and topculprit` as you will be creating multiple elements through loop. The `id` should be unique for any element in HTML document.

Hope the below sample works for you. You can find comments in JS code. You need to write your own CSS to display the items as per your screen shot. I have added `li` element under `ul` element.

```js
var data = {
 "top10": [
  {
   "state": "red",
   "claimed": true,
   "branch": "release-2.3.4",
   "job": "sdk",
   "culprit": "Hansi Meier"
  },
  {
   "state": "blue",
   "claimed": true,
   "branch": "master",
   "job": "ibeo-cloud",
   "culprit": "Karl Gustavo"
  },
  {
   "state": "yellow",
   "claimed": false,
   "branch": "feature-abc",
   "job": "appbase",
   "culprit": "MAfred Auch"
  }
 ]
};

$.each(data.top10, function (i, el) {
 var ele = $(".list-group a.item:first").parent().clone(); //Clone the first element
 ele.find(".topbranch").text(el.branch).css("color", el.state); //Update values
 ele.find(".topjob").text(el.job);
 ele.find(".topculprit").text(el.culprit);
 $(".list-group").append(ele); //Append cloned element to `list-group`
})
$(".list-group a.item:first").parent().remove(); //Remove first li
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav class="side-navbar">
 <div class="title">
  <h1>Top 10</h1>
 </div>

 <ul class="list-group"  style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li>
   <a class="item d-flex align-items-center" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly;">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-up" style="font-size:48px;color:red"></i>
    <div class="item d-table-cell">
     <i class='topbranch'></i><br/>
     <i class='topjob'></i><br/>
     <i class='topculprit'></i><br/>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-refresh" style="font-size:30px;color:yellow"></i>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: how to contact you if i need more help regarding this

Comment: may i know why gave var ele = $(".list-group a.item:first").parent().clone();   why its not working with this  var ele = $(".list-group :first").parent().clone();   what is importance of a. item

Comment: `a.item` gets handle to all `a` elements. `a.item:first` gets handle to first `a` element. Then I get parent of `a` which is `li` then clone the entire `li`.

Comment: super.. @phani kumar M, today I learnt some thing new thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM I want your help to do similar stuff for big html section. I am trying to do same clone logic for that , but i am getting error. Instead of new question , Is there any other way you can help me for that

Comment: @PhaniKumarM clone is really good to do. can you help me  how to do  clone graphs where data is coming from json

Comment: @PhaniKumarM see this question. can you solve that which also similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681287/how-to-send-graph-data-comes-from-json-dynamically-into-html-elements

Answer (score 1):

If you have json array you need to just loop through all objects and read their properties.

Please try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

    var myObj, i, j, x = "";
    myObj = {
        "top10": [
                  {
                      "state": "red",
                      "claimed": true,
                      "branch": "release-2.3.4",
                      "job": "sdk",
                      "culprit": "Hansi Meier"
                  },
                  {
                      "state": "blue",
                      "claimed": true,
                      "branch": "master",
                      "job": "ibeo-cloud",
                      "culprit": "Karl Gustavo"
                  },
                  {
                      "state": "yellow",
                      "claimed": false,
                      "branch": "feature-abc",
                      "job": "appbase",
                      "culprit": "MAfred Auch"
                  }
        ]
    }

    for (i in myObj.top10) {
    x += "<h2>" + myObj.top10[i].branch + "</h2>";
    x += "<h2>" + myObj.top10[i].job + "</h2>";
    x += "<h2>" + myObj.top10[i].culprit + "</h2>";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a modern javascript framework with data binding feature, it's easy to implement and elegant, you can choose from vue, Angular or React.

Comment: yeah but i already started project in simple javascript and jquery

Comment: Then I suggest you may use the Vue framework, it's a progressive framework, you can add the vue js in the script tag, and just new a Vue object will done the data binding things, check out the hello world tutorial, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this iterate over your data.

```
var html;

 $.each(data.top10,function(key1,value1){
html="<div><i id='topbranch'>"+value1.state+"</i><br>"
            +"<i id='topjob'>"+value1.job+"</i><br>"
            +" <i id='topculprit'>"+value1.culprit+"</i></div><br>"
 $("#divId").append(html)
 })
```

here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6w11Ln05/3/
you can add your design accordingly.

Comment: Good one @Vipul Singh

Comment: its helpfull but problem is all the names are coming in one block if you do append. I need get  1st loop of json = 1 block, 2nd loop of json = next block.

Comment: that is because I have added that in one div if you want in separate block add div in the html code dynamically and add css to design properly.